# How I can cancel opening menu when click on arrow?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How I can cancel opening menu when click on arrow? I change arrow on button and I do not need opening menu.

Comment: put a snippet of your code please to understand the context.

Comment: Impossible to answer because there is no way for us to know how your code looks like, what you have so far, and whether or not you have any errors. Please take a look at how to post a [mcve]...

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`openOnClick` to `false`](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#further-options) to prevent the menu from opening when you click the select box.